# Tomcat take 100% CPU

Tags: tomcat, cpu, thread-dump

Tomcat server takes 100% of CPU but only in PRD.
We are not able to reproduce this in other environment.

After taking the thread dump we find there are some threads which are on wating / runnable but not able to find how we can find the root cause.

Can you please help ?

Thread dump has been attached...

## Thread dump 1

2015-12-09 18:14:31
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode):

```
"RMI TCP Connection(7462)-10.16.78.205" - Thread t@15412
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:446)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:192)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:174)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.invoke(StandardMBean.java:405)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1426)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33682.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <59f9a8c> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"JMX server connection timeout 15411" - Thread t@15411
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <154b0510> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(7461)-10.16.78.205" - Thread t@15410
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    - locked <4cd97d50> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <1275bf2a> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3641" - Thread t@15409
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <5ab2369a> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <74b2a2fa> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(7463)-10.17.70.16" - Thread t@15408
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    - locked <12ce5d84> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <444e3680> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3640" - Thread t@15407
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <2a5d8ec1> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <13022c49> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3639" - Thread t@15406
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Object.<init>(Object.java:37)
    at java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:189)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.<init>(CharBuffer.java:276)
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:70)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:369)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:265)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    - locked <7f53b775> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.filter.ResponsePrintWriter.write(ResponsePrintWriter.java:188)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.filter.ResponsePrintWriter.write(ResponsePrintWriter.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.endElement(HtmlResponseWriter.java:576)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.endElement(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:207)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.endElement(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:207)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.endElement(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:207)
    at com.scor.omega2.faces.component.utils.AbstractInputRenderer.encodeDisabledInput(AbstractInputRenderer.java:363)
    at com.scor.omega2.faces.component.dateinputtext.DateInputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(DateInputTextRenderer.java:125)
    at com.scor.omega2.faces.component.dateinputtext.DateInputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(DateInputTextRenderer.java:91)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at com.scor.omega2.faces.component.area.AreaRenderer.encodeEnd(AreaRenderer.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:74)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at com.scor.omega2.faces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:381)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.servlet.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.scor.omega2.core.presentation.servlet.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <5131a3a1> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <22d72971> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3638" - Thread t@15405
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <11edc8ac> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7ed9bb3a> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3637" - Thread t@15403
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <12119d66> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <7fcbb46c> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3636" - Thread t@15402
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <42749cce> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <33c22943> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3635" - Thread t@15401
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <75e2ba77> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <44ea5a2e> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3634" - Thread t@15400
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:924)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    - locked <78401717> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <68f5931a> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(7454)-10.17.70.16" - Thread t@15398
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <48f267ec> (a com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer.fetchNotifications(ArrayNotificationBuffer.java:435)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer$ShareBuffer.fetchNotifications(ArrayNotificationBuffer.java:227)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerNotifForwarder.fetchNotifs(ServerNotifForwarder.java:274)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$3.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1288)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$3.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1286)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.fetchNotifications(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1294)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Mike I update a thread dump but it is not full because of limitations.

Comment: Just strip all the "at ..." except the first (top) "at" for each thread.

Comment: Yes but It may not be much.. The main thing you would see is that there is some blocking at t org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:516) but I am not sure how we can drill down

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0" is contributing to high CPU. Generally "java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0" means the server is waiting to hear back from the other end and the other end is slow in responding. If you don't see "java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0" in your other environments, you should check the other end of this particular environment (for slowness).

There are two possibilities : 1. There could be other threads which are contributing to the problem (Use "top" with "H" option to find out threads which are consuming most of your CPU). 
2. GC could be contributing to high CPU.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34103732/406896) of mine if that helps you. Your feedback is welcome, so that I can fine tune my answer.